# py2app で作成したアプリを dist フォルダ内で実行するとエラーになる

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

macOS10.13High Sierraでpy2apでtkinterのドキュメントにある「簡単な Hello World プログラム」をvenvで仮想環境構築をしアプリ化しようとしたところ、アプリの作成自体には成功するものの作成されたアプリを実行しようとするとエラーとなります。良い解決方法はございますでしょうか。御教授頂けましたらと思います。

macOS10.13.6 High Sierra
Python 3.6.5
Xcode 10.1
command Line Tool
`PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework"` オプション付きインストール

**エラー内容**

```
/Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/MacOS/HelloWorld ; exit;
MacBook-Pro:~ userName$ /Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/MacOS/HelloWorld ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 101, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/Resources/HelloWorld.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "tkinter/__init__.pyc", line 36, in <module>
ValueError: character U+6573552f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
2020-06-03 15:00:57.139 HelloWorld[27708:726970] HelloWorld Error
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

その後、pyenv + venvでTkinterを使うにはActiveTcl-8.5が必要だとのことで、ActiveTcl-8.5をインストール後Pythonを再インストールし再度バイナリ化をしてみたところ、_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directoriesというエラーメッセージへと変化しました。現状はここで止まっております。

```
/Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/MacOS/HelloWorld ; exit;
userNameMacBook-Pro:~ userName$ /Users/hisashishindo/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/MacOS/HelloWorld ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 81, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 66, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/Resources/HelloWorld.py", line 22, in <module>
    root = tk.Tk()
  File "tkinter/__init__.pyc", line 2020, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk8.5 /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tk8.5 /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/lib/tk8.5 /Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/lib/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts ~/Library/Tcl/tk8.5 ~/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Tcl/tk8.5 /Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /System/Library/Tcl/tk8.5 /System/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts ~/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5 ~/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Frameworks/tk8.5 /Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /System/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5 /System/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Tcl/teapot/package/macosx10.5-i386-x86_64/lib/tk8.5 /Library/Tcl/teapot/package/macosx10.5-i386-x86_64/lib/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Tcl/teapot/package/tcl/lib/tk8.5 /Library/Tcl/teapot/package/tcl/lib/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/lib/tk8.5 /Users/userName/Documents/HelloWorlddocs/dist/HelloWorld.app/Contents/library



This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.

2020-06-04 09:57:13.141 HelloWorld[16816:1215156] HelloWorld Error
called Tcl_FindHashEntry on deleted table
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

Comment: エラーメッセージにある、`ValueError: character U+6573552f is not in range` で検索してみると、[ValueError: character U+6573552f... Py2aap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493029/valueerror-character-u6573552f-py2aap) が参考になりそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。py2appは0.21がインストールされていたため参考の通りpip install py2app==0.13に下げて再度アプリ化してみましたがエラーのため起動することができませんでした。エラー内容はほぼ変わらずでした。

Comment: pyenv + venvでTkinterを使うにはActiveTcl-8.5が必要だとのことで、ActiveTcl-8.5をインストール後Pythonを再インストールし再度バイナリ化をしてみたところ、_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directoriesというエラーメッセージへと変化しました。内容については上記質問へ追記します。